# testing your rails app in IE8 through virtualbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, macos, virtualbox

I am developing a rails application in my mac and testing at localhost:/3000
I need to test some of the features in IE8.
I downloaded virtualbox and set up a VM for it.
I had my rails service running in my mac tried the following different ways but didnt work.

```
http://192.168.1.2:3000
```

Did ipconfig in windows cmd and found out the IP address was 10.0.2.15.

```
http://10.0.2.15:3000
```

Did a host name on my mac  and tried the following in my windows:

```
mac-hostname:3000
```

But none of the above worked.

Comment: if your VM is on 10.0.2.15 is not going to reach 192.168.1.2 w/o proper routing. Why did the VM get such a wildly different IP? One would expect they're both configured by same  DHCP. Perhaps the VM's virtual network adapter is not attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the issue.
I updated the /etc/hosts file
I added the IP address and renamed the localhost to something else

```
10.0.2.2 localtest
```

And in my broswer I enter:

```
http://localtest:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working. Check your VM settings. In my case the Network tab has 'Attached to:' set to NAT.

The host address (192.168.1.2) is where you should point your browser. The 10.0.2.15 address belongs to the VM client. You should be able to open a command window in the VM and do `tracert 192.168.1.2` and get there in 2 hops.

P.S.: You may also be able to get this working with a bridged adapter. I'm just telling you what works for me.